# I want to Out-File a special line, but can't seem to get it done?

Tags: powershell, output

I have this script:

```
function Get-LastBootUpTime {            
    param (
        $ComputerName
    )
    $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName               
    [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)            
}

$Days = -1
$ShutdownDate = (Get-Date).adddays($days)

$ComputerList = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' -Filter '*' |
                Select -EXP Name

$ComputerList | foreach {
    $Bootup = Get-LastBootUpTime -ComputerName $_

    Write-Host "$_ last booted: $Bootup"

    if ($ShutdownDate -gt $Bootup) {
        Write-Host "Rebooting Computer: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
        Restart-Computer $_ -Force
    } else {
        Write-Host "No need to reboot: $_" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

It shuts down every PC which is longer than 1 days online.

It works fine, but I also want to have an `Out-File` as a .txt which shows which PC got shutdown. So either the message "PCx needs to shutdown" or the uptime of PCx. I tried to do it with `Out-File`, but it never reads the information I want. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Powershell and what does "...it never reads the information I want..." mean?

Comment: I don't see an `Out-File` anywhere in your code. Please show the code that is not working and explain how *exactly* the results are different from what you expected.

Comment: @rrirower it means the .txt file is always empty and I use powershell 5

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers like I said in the other comment the .txt is always empty no matter where I put it, so I deleted it out of the script. At first I thought that it would work at
Write-Host "$_ last booted: $Bootup" | Out-File "C:\textfile.txt"

Comment: As an alternative, have you tried using Set-Content?  I've found it very easy to use for text files.

Comment: have you looked at `Out-File -InputObject` might be what you need to fix yours.

Comment: `Write-Host` writes to the host console. Its output cannot be processed via a pipeline. You need to use `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host` if you want to pipe the string into `Out-File` (or related cmdlet). Use `Tee-Object` if you want the information both displayed and written to a file. I suspected it might be something like that, which is exactly why I asked you to show the code that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the `Tee-Object`-command:

`"$_ last booted: $Bootup" | tee -Append log.txt`

it will append the text to the file and print it on the screen.

Comment: where is the file saved? Because if I write exactly your line nothing happens. When I write tee -Append C:\log.txt it doesn't save either.